# F#'s Scaffold and FsUnit/FsCheck

Tags: f#, mono

I'm struggling to get started with F# on Linux using ProjectScaffold.
Specifically: I can't get a project to work with FsUnit/FsCheck/xunit. I
have F# 3.1 and mono 3.12.1 and I'm on Linux (Ubuntu) x64.

I start "MyProject" with:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:fsprojects/ProjectScaffold.git
$ cd ProjectScaffold && ./build.sh
```

Then I add a bit of code to "src/MyProject/Library.fs":

```
module MyProject.X

let four = 4
```

And then two tests to "tests/MyProject.Tests/Tests.fs":

```
module MyProject.Tests.X

open Xunit
open FsUnit.Xunit
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit
open MyProject.X

[<Fact>]
let ``Two plus two is four.`` () =
    2 + 2 |> should equal four

[<Property>]
let ``Sorting a sorted list is idempotent.`` (l: int list) =
    let s = List.sort l
    s = List.sort s
```

This code works on Visual Studio where I manually added FsCheck, FsUnit, anx xunit 1.9.2 (it fails with later version
for some reason). My test project on Windows/Visual Studio has this config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FsCheck" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FsCheck.Xunit" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FsUnit.xUnit" version="1.3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit" version="1.9.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

So I edit paket.dependencies to add these packages and remove Nunit:

```
source https://nuget.org/api/v2

nuget FSharp.Formatting 2.8.0
nuget FSharpVSPowerTools.Core 1.7.0
nuget FAKE
nuget FsCheck 1.0.4
nuget FsCheck.Xunit 1.0.4
nuget FsUnit.xUnit 1.3.0.1
nuget xunit 1.9.2
nuget SourceLink.Fake

github fsharp/FAKE modules/Octokit/Octokit.fsx
```

Then:

```
$ mono .paket/paket.exe install
```

...and it fails because NUnit is referenced somewhere, so I delete the references in tests/MyProject.Tests/paket.references and

```
$ mono .paket/paket.exe install
```

works, but

```
$ ./build.sh
```

fails, at it cannot find references to FsCheck et al. So I assume that I need to add the references manually, so tests/MyProject.Tests/paket.references is now:

```
FsCheck
FsCheck.Xunit
FsUnit.xUnit
xunit
```

...built build.sh fails again: it cannot find FsCheck. I could not find in the paket doc how to add a local dependency (MyProject.Tests should reference MyProject), it might be done automatically.

Comment: Decide if you want to use NuGet (and add references from within VS) or paket, don't mix them like this! Keep your paket.references, delete all nuget packages and references (from within visual studio) and run `paket install` (this should re-add all references for you). Project references are untouched by paket, so just add them as you normally do via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it took a while for me to figure out a fix.  For the project file in the Tests directory, I had to change this:

```
<Reference Include="FsUnit.NUnit">
    <HintPath>..\..\packages\FsUnit.1.3.0.1\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.NUnit.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

To this:

```
<Reference Include="FsUnit.NUnit">
    <HintPath>..\..\packages\FsUnit\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.NUnit.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Similarly, for NUnit:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\NUnit.2.6.3\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

To:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\NUnit\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The issue is that on mono, the packages don't have the version in the path but under Visual Studio they do.  Once I found this fix, I created two .fsproj files for the tests and I modified the build.sh script to swap the mono-compatible one in when under mono via:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test "$OS" = "Windows_NT"
then
  # no changes in here
else
  # fix test fsproj file
  mv tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj.vs
  mv tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj.mono tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj  

  # leave the script logic for mono in place

  # put project files back to avoid git noticing the swap
  mv tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj.mono
  mv tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj.vs tests/ProjectName.Tests/ProjectName.Tests.fsproj

fi
```

Once I made these changes the project works fine under both Visual Studio as well as mono.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to be the problem. The project file does have the right reference for the dll, I have no idea why I get "The namespace or module 'FsCheck' is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, I understand you: Do you have two fsproj files, one for the production code and one for the unit tests? And are you referencing FsCheck in the fsproj?

Plus, I remember an issue, where if you compile against an older version of .net and reference an assembly compiled against a newer version of .net, it will behave as though there was no reference.